# loop methods in vueJs

Tags: vuejs2

is there a way to repeat the methods in VueJS instance I seemed to try every syntax possible  like injecting traditional for-loop and it didn't work. I have no clue and ended up writing the methods myself.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried and explain what isn't working as expected?

Comment: see I said I have no clue, I tried to make something like                methods:{for(x=0;x<4;x++){update(){return x ;};}                                                        just to repeat the method and increment, not sure if something like that exists but it's does in java script so just wondering

Comment: You're just asking [how to write a for loop in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)?

Comment: of course not that what I am asking , what I am asking is that "I am trying to use the for loop in VueJS  instance so that I can loop over a method. so if I have "update()" method how can I repeat it while incrementing a variable in VueJS is it the same like in Javascript ???

Comment: Yes, it's the same. People will be willing to help you with your issue, but only if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will write one now. thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Maybe you mean "v-for" within the vue templates? Guess we'll see when you post a fiddle or some code!

Answer (score 0):

The methods property contains... methods!
You can do whatever you want **inside** its definition, not outside of it...

```
methods: {
     methodname: function() {
         var x = 0;
         for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
             i += 4;
         }
     }
}
```

Hope that helps